# JBoss Compatibility with Windows Server 2008

Tags: jboss

Our product uses the JBoss 4.0.4 as an application server. Currently we are supporting Windows Server 2003 and planning to support Windows Server 2008. We want to know that is JBoss 4.0.4 fully compatible with Windows Server 2008 (64 bit)?

Please respond if anybody installed and used JBoss with Windows 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since JBoss is 100% pure Java you can have it working on any Operating System that supports Java. So I guess that the real question is more "does my JVM run correctly on Windows 2008". According to [this guide](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Installation_Guide/4/html-single/index.html), JBoss needs a JDK 1.5 and should run on a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM on a 64-bit Windows 2008 machine.

Comment: Thanks Pascal.
 
Your answer is logically true but I am expecting more practical answers.
 
Please let me know your experience on JBoss uses on Windows 2008.